# Java Swing BSAF with WindowBuilder Pro

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

Has anyone had any success in using [BSAF](http://kenai.com/projects/bsaf/pages/Home) with WindowBuilder Pro on Eclipse Indigo?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use BASAF with windowbuilder, it is also part of [windowbuilder-extras](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/windowbuilder-extras/) project .

Comment: Thanks aleroot but I checked out your link and did not find much there. Are you saying that you can use Better Swing Application Framework with WindowBuilder? Have you actually done it? Have you a small example? I'm really after the session state stuff for my project...